# Sqlboiler doesn't work with variable originated from c.Query in gin framework

Tags: go, sqlboiler

I want to use sqlboiler with a variable which come from c.Query() in gin framework, but sqlboiler returns ERROR: `sql: no rows in result set`. Are there any ways to pass the variable?
Here is my sample code:

```
func getUser(c *gin.Context){
    name := c.Query("name")
    /* some db setting */
    user, err := models.Users(
        qm.WhereIn("name in ?", name),
    ).One(ctx, db)
}
```

I know that this works:

```
func getUser(){
    name := "John"
    /* some db setting */
    user, err := models.Users(
        qm.WhereIn("name in ?", name),
    ).One(ctx, db)
}
```

Comment: Using “qm.Where“ instead of ”qm.WhereIn“ should resolve the issue when working with a single variable.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe try to use"qm.Expr"```qm.Expr("name IN ?", pq.StringArray{name}),'''

Comment: thx, but it also fail...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the reason why sql: no rows in result set occurs is failure in my get request.

I called request in next format: http://localhost:8080/api/user?name="John".
However, right request format is here: http://localhost:8080/api/user?name=John.

Just, I remove double quotes, and sqlboiler can search John, not "John".